# Subscription form CSS editing

Tags: css, forms

I need to edit this subscription form so that the email box and the button are all 290px wide and all centred. I also want to make the button black and not to have rounded edges. Can anyone help with this please?

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;  width:290px;}
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//thefacefactory.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=95d25bd530e274cd2b9abd235&amp;id=411d7026eb" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">The Face Factory Newsletter</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" arial-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_95d25bd530e274cd2b9abd235_411d7026eb" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Receive Offers and Beauty Tips" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: Show us what CSS you already tried and describe what it did not do correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding in the following style to your existing CSS `<style>` block :

```
/* Target your subscribe button */
#mc-embedded-subscribe { 
      /* Ensure that the background is black (#000) */
      background-color: #000!important; 
      /* Ignore any rounded corners */
      border-radius: 0!important;
}
```

You can [see a working example here](http://jsbin.com/kicipo/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Thats great thank you! Do you know how to centre everything and make the email box the same size as everything else please?

Comment: If you want to center everything, try using [these styles](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/d25c5af5d2652d7d15bdf2c6b35ae0b3) which can be [seen here](http://jsbin.com/kicipo/edit?html,output).

Comment: Thank you, iv'e just been trying to make the email box the same size as the black button and not sure what Ive done but its not worked and is now touching the black button?

Comment: You may likely want to add some top and bottom margin to your e-mail box, which can be done via `#mc_embed_signup input.email { margin: 10px auto;}`. That will center it horizontally and add 10px of top and bottom margin to separate it from other elements.

Comment: Thanks thats worked, do you know how to make the email box wider so it is the same size as the black button? Last question I promise.

Comment: There are a few ways to handle that, however the easiest might be to just adjust the `min-width` property on the same element : `#mc_embed_signup input.email { margin: 10px auto; min-width: 230px; }`